# How can I share swatch palette between desktop and laptop?

Tags: swatches

I recently bought a laptop to take out to appointments.  I use a set palette of about 400 colors.  How can I find the file and copy that to my laptop without recreating each color?

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop/Illustrator go Window>Swatches then in the top right corner click the 3 lines icon and Save Swatches. Then load these on another computer the same way.

Otherwise create a doc with all the colours as already mentioned here.

Comment: In indesign, in addition to export/import to a swatch file, one can import swatches directly from an existing document.

Answer (score 0):

For just about any software, the most foolproof way to do this (and this isn't fun) is to make a new file, draw a shape for each colour, put one colour on each shape, and share that file with yourself.

Otherwise you'll need to be more specific about the app you're using.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to have a central repository where you store swatches. Export all your swatches to a cloud service like Dropbox / Google Drive and import them on your new machine. Another option is to store all your swatches on [kuler.adobe.com](http://kuler.adobe.com/). You can access them from any machine.